# Modal dialogue through the navbar in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So this is a question that I've been fiddling with for a bit.  I have a WordPress driven website, based on Bootstrap 3.  I'm trying to have a link inside my navbar that when clicked, opens a modal dialogue.  Now, the modal code is correct, but I'm unsure how to work the correct code for the link

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Into the navigation bar since it is called from wp_nav_menu a la

```
            <?php
               wp_nav_menu(array(
                  'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
                  'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
                  'menu_id'         => 'Main Menu',
                  'walker'          => new Cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
              ));
            ?>
```

and the only options within WordPress available are url and link text.  Am I missing something?

EDIT:

I've tried to accomplish this via jQuery as per a tip I saw online but am having trouble accomplishing it.  The menu item ID is **menu-item-221**

Here is my jQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    jQUery("#menu-item-221").click(function(){
        jQuery("#paymentmodal").modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out..  The menu item cannot possess an href link for it to work.  I believe that the browser tries to go to the link before the jQuery is called.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with adding preventDefault() to the code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    jQuery("#menu-item-221").click(function(e){
        jQuery("#paymentmodal").modal('show');
e.preventDefault();
    });
```